# Problem with dictionary iteration in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, iteration, typeerror

I am new to python so maybe my problem is easy to solve.
I have a dictionary organized as follow:
my_dict = {'x': (1.1, 3.4), 'y': (4.3, 7.5), 'z': (7.3, 9.5)}. 
I would like to reduce each value by the same number, so this is what I am trying to do:

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    for a, b in v:
        a = a * 0.3
        b = b * 0.3 
        my_dict[k] = (a, b)
return my_dict
```

When using this code, I receive this error:

```
for a, b in v:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

So it seems that the "for a, b in v" loop is trying to iterate through float, which is not possible.
Thus, I tried to print my_dict.items() and k,v in the for loop, in order to see what is the for loop iterate through, and this is what I get:

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    print my_dict.items()
    print k,v

[('x', (1.1, 3.4)), ('y', (4.3, 7.5)), ('z', (7.3, 9.5))]
y (4.3, 7.5)
```

I can see two wierd things:
- I was expecting the "print k,v" command to print each key, values couple, but I am getting only the y key with its value
- By looking at the my_dict.items(), it seems to me that v is not a float, but a tuple containing two float. So why do I get the float object is not iterable error?

Any help is well appreciated.
Again, I am sorry if this is a silly question, but I just started using python and I am stuck with this.

Thank you!

Comment: You simply meant `a, b = v` to unpack the tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dict comprehension here

```
>>> {k: tuple(i * 0.3 for i in v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
{'x': (0.33, 1.02), 'y': (1.2899999999999998, 2.25), 'z': (2.19, 2.85)}
```

Comment: This sound great! Thanks! What if I want to make a * 0.3 and b * 0.5?

Comment: In that case, use `(v[0]*0.3, v[1]*0.5)`.

Comment: You could also do it with something more general, such as `(i * c for i, c in zip(v, (0.3, 0.5)) for k, v ...)`

Answer (score 1):

@CoryKramer already nailed the Pythonic way to do this.
To focus on *your* code ...

Your inner "loop" isn't the right technique.
You do not need to *iterate* through the tuple -- that takes one element at a time, and you want two at once.  Rather, you need to "unpack" the tuple.

```
my_dict = {'x': (1.1, 3.4), 'y': (4.3, 7.5), 'z': (7.3, 9.5)}

for k,v in my_dict.items():
    print("dict:", k, v)
    a, b = v
    print("val:", a, b)
    a = a * 0.3
    b = b * 0.3
    my_dict[k] = (a, b)
```

Comment: you can use for k, (a, b) in my_dict.items(): and save one line of code)

Comment: I know -- I'm doing my best to keep close to OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code `for a, b in v` doesn't make sense because there is only one value `v` which is your tuple. You are already looping through the items in the dictionary in your outer loop. Try the following:

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    a, b = v
    a = a * 0.3
    b = b * 0.3 
    my_dict[k] = (a, b)
return my_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here, is that by doing:

```
for a, b in v
```

You are trying to iterate over a single tuple, which does not really make sense since *you're already unpacking it*.

Note that all you'd need is to unpack its values as:

```
k,v = next(iter(my_dict.items()))
a, b = v
```

Now `a` and `b` contains both tuple values respectively. So the only issue in your code is that inner `for`.

So it is clear that it does not make sense, but *why does the error occur?*

This is because Python is expecting `v` to be an iterable of iterables, since you're trying to unpack each iterable into `k` and `v`. In this case, when you iterate over `v`, the first item to be returned is its first `float`, which cannot be unpacked.

Note that if we instead iterated over a list containing the tuple, your approach would work:

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    for a, b in [v]:
        a = a * 0.3
        b = b * 0.3 
        my_dict[k] = (a, b)
```

Though, as mentioned it does not make sense, given that you can just directly unpack them:

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    a, b = v
    a = a * 0.3
    b = b * 0.3 
    my_dict[k] = (a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to iterate over the tuple but just assign it to variables:

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    a, b = v
    a = a * 0.3
    b = b * 0.3 
    my_dict[k] = (a, b)
return my_dict
```

and a bit nicer solution:

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[k] = tuple([0.3*x for x in v])
return my_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

you can unpack your dict values:

```
for k, (a, b) in my_dict.items():
    a *= 0.3
    b *= 0.3 
    my_dict[k] = (a, b)
```

or you can use:

```
dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1][0]*0.3, x[1][1]*0.3)),   my_dict.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a dictionary comprehension:

```
my_dict = {'x': (1.1, 3.4), 'y': (4.3, 7.5), 'z': (7.3, 9.5)}

f = 0.3
my_dict = {k:(a*f,b*f) for k,(a,b) in my_dict.items()}

print(my_dict)  # {'x': (0.33, 1.02), 'y': (1.2899999999999998, 2.25), 'z': (2.19, 2.85)}
```

If you want to keep the loop, you will have to remove the nested for-loop because it is not needed to expand the tuples.  You can simply write it like this:

```
for k,(a,b) in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[k] = (a*0.3, b*0.3)
```